# Test running a cloud-init userdata file

Tags: cloud, amazon-ec2, cloud-init

A cloud-config userdata file looks great for initialization, but how can you iteratively go about developing and testing it?

The feedback delay is just too high if you need to provision instances every time until you get everything right.

Assume a toy instance in AWS or equivalent with a userdata *file*, how can I run have cloud-init run it manually, after boot?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23065673/how-to-re-run-cloud-init-without-reboot looks like a start but it is not clear how to change the userdata between each run

Comment: It feels as if there should be a command of the form `cloud-init run-file my-user-data`  I have looked but I can't find such a thing.

Answer (score 0):

Need not reboot every time, clean all cache files of cloud-init (rm -rf /var/lib/cloud), then run cloud init command with one by one.

Comment: Tried that: the userdata is fetched from AWS and it's the same. The problem is reading that from *file* instead